# Convert string to list or array

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a string such as:

```
["aaaaa","bbbbb","ccccc","ddddd","eeeee"]
```

How would I convert this to a list or an array?

I am new to c# programming and this seemingly simple problem has got me stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like JSON... If it is indeed JSON using proper parser like JSON.Net is better approach.

Comment: Use a proper library if possible. You might have some special case happen in the futur (ex: having double quote inside a string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, first remove square brackets then use `Split`:

```
var str = "[\"aaaaa\",\"bbbbb\",\"ccccc\",\"ddddd\",\"eeeee\"]";
var list = str.TrimStart('[')
              .TrimEnd(']')
              .Split(new []{ '"', ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```